# Nginx setup for Angular front-end & Laravel api on

Tags: angularjs, angular, laravel, nginx, hosting

I have setup my front-end Angular application in the www directory and has setup a Laravel back-end application as following directory structure.

```
/application
    /app
    /bootstrap
    /vendor   
    /public
        /api 
            index.php <-- Laravel "public" index
```

I currently use  following setup. It is not working.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name my_domain.com www.my_domain.com;
    root /var/www/my_domain.com;

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location /api {
        root /var/www/my_domain.com/api/public;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
     }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Can you point out my mistake.

Comment: How do you expect it to work? using `api` prefix?

Comment: yes. I'm thinking of my_domain.com for website and my_domain.com/api for the api